# Error while Joomla 2.5.28 to Joomla 3.4 update

Tags: php, joomla

I have a website on Joomla! 2.5.28 and i want to update it the latest version.

I followed this tutorial: https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_2.5_to_3.x_Step_by_Step_Migration and tried to migrate.

I deactivated "Remember Me" Plugin, "Fix"ed Database from Extension Manager -> Database. I dont' have any third party extensions. Only core Joomla! extensions.

When i click "Install the Update", i get this error:

```
1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=-- -- Dumping data for table `joomla_content_types` -- INSERT INTO `joomla_content_types` (`type_id`, `type_title`, `type_alias`, `table`, `rules`, `field_mappings`,`router`) VALUES (1, 'Article', 'com_content.article', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__content","key":"id","type":"Content","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__core_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":[{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"state","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created","core_modified_time":"modified","core_body":"introtext", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"publish_up","core_publish_down":"publish_down","core_access":"access", "core_params":"attribs", "core_featured":"featured", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"images", "core_urls":"urls", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"ordering", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"catid", "core_xreference":"xreference", "asset_id":"asset_id"}], "special": [{"fulltext":"fulltext"}]}','ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute'), (2, 'Weblink', 'com_weblinks.weblink', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__weblinks","key":"id","type":"Weblink","prefix":"WeblinksTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__core_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":[{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"state","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created","core_modified_time":"modified","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"publish_up","core_publish_down":"publish_down","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"featured", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"images", "core_urls":"urls", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"ordering", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"catid", "core_xreference":"xreference", "asset_id":"null"}], "special": []}','WeblinksHelperRoute::getWeblinkRoute'), (3, 'Contact', 'com_contact.contact', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__contact_details","key":"id","type":"Contact","prefix":"ContactTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__core_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":[{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"name","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created","core_modified_time":"modified","core_body":"address", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"publish_up","core_publish_down":"publish_down","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"featured", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"image", "core_urls":"webpage", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"ordering", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"catid", "core_xreference":"xreference", "asset_id":"null"}], "special": [{"con_position":"con_position","suburb":"suburb","state":"state","country":"country","postcode":"postcode","telephone":"telephone","fax":"fax","misc":"misc","email_to":"email_to","default_con":"default_con","user_id":"user_id","mobile":"mobile","sortname1":"sortname1","sortname2":"sortname2","sortname3":"sortname3"}]}','ContactHelperRoute::getContactRoute'), (4, 'Newsfeed', 'com_newsfeeds.newsfeed', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__newsfeeds","key":"id","type":"Newsfeed","prefix":"NewsfeedsTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__core_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":[{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"name","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created","core_modified_time":"modified","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"publish_up","core_publish_down":"publish_down","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"featured", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"images", "core_urls":"link", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"ordering", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"catid", "core_xreference":"xreference", "asset_id":"null"}], "special": [{"numarticles":"numarticles","cache_time":"cache_time","rtl":"rtl"}]}','NewsfeedsHelperRoute::getNewsfeedRoute'), (5, 'User', 'com_users.user', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__users","key":"id","type":"User","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__core_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":[{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"name","core_state":"null","core_alias":"username","core_created_time":"registerdate","core_modified_time":"lastvisitDate","core_body":"null", "core_hits":"null","core_publish_up":"null","core_publish_down":"null","access":"null", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"null", "core_metadata":"null", "core_language":"null", "core_images":"null", "core_urls":"null", "core_version":"null", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"null", "core_metadesc":"null", "core_catid":"null", "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"null"}], "special": [{}]}','UsersHelperRoute::getUserRoute'), (6, 'Article Category', 'com_content.category', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__categories","key":"id","type":"Category","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__core_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":[{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created_time","core_modified_time":"modified_time","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"null","core_publish_down":"null","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"null", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"null", "core_urls":"null", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"parent_id", "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"asset_id"}], "special": [{"parent_id":"parent_id","lft":"lft","rgt":"rgt","level":"level","path":"path","extension":"extension","note":"note"}]}','ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute'), (7, 'Contact Category', 'com_contact.category', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__categories","key":"id","type":"Category","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__core_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":[{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created_time","core_modified_time":"modified_time","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"null","core_publish_down":"null","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"null", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"null", "core_urls":"null", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"parent_id", "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"asset_id"}], "special": [{"parent_id":"parent_id","lft":"lft","rgt":"rgt","level":"level","path":"path","extension":"extension","note":"note"}]}','ContactHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute'), (8, 'Newsfeeds Category', 'com_newsfeeds.category', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__categories","key":"id","type":"Category","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__core_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":[{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created_time","core_modified_time":"modified_time","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"null","core_publish_down":"null","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"null", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"null", "core_urls":"null", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"parent_id", "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"asset_id"}], "special": [{"parent_id":"parent_id","lft":"lft","rgt":"rgt","level":"level","path":"path","extension":"extension","note":"note"}]}','NewsfeedsHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute'), (9, 'Weblinks Category', 'com_weblinks.category', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__categories","key":"id","type":"Category","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__core_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":[{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created_time","core_modified_time":"modified_time","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"null","core_publish_down":"null","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"null", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"null", "core_urls":"null", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"parent_id", "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"asset_id"}], "special": [{"parent_id":"parent_id","lft":"lft","rgt":"rgt","level":"level","path":"path","extension":"extension","note":"note"}]}','WeblinksHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute'), (10, 'Tag', 'com_tags.tag', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__tags","key":"tag_id","type":"Tag","prefix":"TagsTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__core_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":[{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created_time","core_modified_time":"modified_time","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"null","core_publish_down":"null","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"featured", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"images", "core_urls":"urls", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"null", "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"null"}], "special": [{"parent_id":"parent_id","lft":"lft","rgt":"rgt","level":"level","path":"path"}]}','TagsHelperRoute::getTagRoute');
```

The website is hosted on Google Cloud Compute Engine.

I searched online but couldn't find an answer. Any idea what can be done to update Joomla!?

Answer (score 0):

Restore the fully functional 2.5.28 version.
Verify that table and content (_content_types) does NOT exist. If you find the table, "drop" that table. http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=875050